# What the name of this connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I've spent a load of time looking for the answer to this question, but I cannot find it. What is the official name of this connector?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a female crimp terminal (sometimes called an open barrel or u-barrel crimp connector). More specifically, since it has the plastic housing, it's called a PCB female crimp terminal.

Seems like that information was available from where you apparently got the image on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/100-crimp-housings-and-terminals-connector-2pos-20pcs-/300895450274?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item460ec434a2)

If the case was that you happened across this image out of context, I recommend [images.google.com](http://images.google.com). Google lets you search by image, basically you can bypass the 1000 words by just uploading the image.

Comment: wow lol, scared me there fore a moment. I wasn't aware of that tool. Actually I found that image from ebay through a few search terms, however I was never aware of the official name. Thanks for your input, I'll consider PCB female crimp terminal as the actual name.

Answer (score 3):

The metallic parts are called crimp connectors - typically sold in strips such as in the photo, and removed from the strip before / after crimping to wire.

The black plastic parts are called **single row crimp connector housings**. They would be specified with pitch (distance between centers of each slot) at the least, with the common ones being **0.1" single row crimp connector housings**.

The housings are available in singles, twos (as in the image in the question), threes, and so on, as well as in single, double, and even triple rows, maybe more.

Answer (score 1):

At http://uk.rs-online.com, search for M20-1060200. They call it "M20 CRIMP HOUSING, SIL, 2w, 2.54mm"

Answer (score 0):

On places like eBay and Aliexpress they're often called Dupont connectors, although they are made by many different manufacturers and the DuPont company makes so many other types of connectors it is surprising their name ended up being attached to these ones.